# Python code for polymorphism with random number generator

Tags: python

I would like to create a generic random variable whose distribution depends on a certain condition, and then generate a sequence of random variable according to the retained distribution. For example,

```
if (condition):
    RV = np.random.normal

""" The above command will assign the standard normal distribution to RV. 
I do not know how to assign the normal distribution with mean $m$ and variance sigma^2.

"""
else:
    RV = np.random.exponential
```

""" Similar problem here. 
I do not know how to assign the shape parameter of the exponential distribution.
"""

""" generate a sample of size 10 from the distribution a 
"""
for i in range(0,9):
    RV.next()   # I would like a generic function "next" to generate the next number in the sequence

The above code will create a random variable with the standard normal distribution if the condition is satisfied, else it will assign an exponential number generator with unit shape parameter to RV.

I would like to know how to initialize RV with a different mean (or other parameters of the distribution) than the default assignment.

Comment: `numpy.random.normal(avg, stdev)` - http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.normal.html

Comment: `numpy.random.exponential(scale=1.0, size=None)` is a little more complicated, but scale is related to the shape. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.exponential.html

Comment: Thanks for your comment. But that would generate {\it only one} random number according to the normal distribution with (avg, stdev). I am looking to attach assign a distribution from which I can sample as many times I like

Comment: There's a size parameter for both of these as well. So, normal(avg, stdev, size)

Comment: Yes, but I would like to generate on the fly. I do not know a priori how many numbers I need.

Comment: Oh! you want `functools.partials`

Comment: That works! Thanks a lot!  If you make your last comment into an answer, I shall accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, from languages like Haskell hail the partial function. Basically, a partial function is a function...with some of the `args` pre-filled.

Python also supports partial functions, in versions 2.5 and above: https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

```
from functools import partial

if (condition):
    RV = partial(np.random.normal, loc=avg, scale=stdev)
else:
    RV = partial(np.random.exponential, scale=scale)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use scipy.stats. E.g.

```
import scipy.stats
r = scipy.stats.uniform() # or other distribution chosen dynamically

random_range = r.rvs(size = 10)
```

Comment: Thanks for the elegant solution! It is indeed helpful. I read NightShadeQueen's answer first, and accepted it.